# Loss of host-only network in VmWare after moving vm directory

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

I'm using VMWare Workstation 12, and have moved a vm from one drive to another. Up restarting the machine, I lost all of the networking (there are two network devices connected, one for a NAT connection, and the other is host-only), so after removing and re-adding the two network devices, I have a working NAT connection, but the host-only connection doesn't auto-connect.

I've tried `if config eth1 up` which show the device as active but with no inet address (only an ip6 address). I've tried everything but restarting the host (which I can't do as I have a long-running process occurring).

Answer (score 0):

For myself and everybody elses future reference (and many hours of frustrating searching, and reading) - I have to add the eth1 to the /ect/network/interfaces for some reason. eth0 was already defined, but not eth1. After adding and restarting, the device appeared on the network with an IP address.